# Sticky Navegation o Scrolling for elemetor

Tags: css, wordpress, widget, elementor

I have tried to make a navigation through the fixed option of a menu in elementor as it is in the image. [Imagen Fixed left Navegator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPRLi.gif)

Use the sticky options to do the function that I present in an image. and it does something similar to moving the mouse leaving the navigation fixed to the left side but it does not leave any link active while I scroll down or up etc.

The question is, is there any elementor plugin that does this function or is there simply a tutorial to do it step by step. Because I haven't really found anything.